# Unity / How to set Limit for enemy spawn?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I managed to spawn enemies but they keep spawning. How can I set a limit to avoid from spawning unceasingly?

I've tried to add spawnLimit and spawnCounter  but couldn't manage it to work.

```
var playerHealth = 100;     // Reference to the player's heatlh.
var enemy : GameObject;                // The enemy prefab to be spawned.
var spawnTime : float = 3f;            // How long between each spawn.
var spawnPoints : Transform[];         // An array of the spawn points this enemy can spawn from.


function Start ()
{
    // Call the Spawn function after a delay of the spawnTime and then continue to call after the same amount of time.
    InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime);
}


function Spawn ()
{
    // If the player has no health left...
    if(playerHealth <= 0f)
    {
        // ... exit the function.
        return;
    }


    // Find a random index between zero and one less than the number of spawn points.
    var spawnPointIndex : int = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);

    // Create an instance of the enemy prefab at the randomly selected spawn point's position and rotation.
    Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this kind of counter:

```
int maxEnemies = 100;
int enemiyCounter = 0;
```

and in `Spawn()` add:

```
if(enemiyCounter < maxEnemies){
    Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
    enemyCounter++;
}
```

instead of

```
Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer that @ukasz-motyczka gave is great for a one-time spawn, but if you want a continuous spawn (every time an enemy is killed it is replaced), then you will need to dynamically count how many enemies there are.

Duck gives a good answer on [how to count enemies](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/9821/how-do-i-count-or-get-references-to-all-gameobject.html)

If you combine his code with ukasz-motyczka's then you can drop the variable to keep track of how many enemies you've spawned since you are dynamically counting them.  You would get something like this:

```
int maxEnemies = 100;
```

and in Spawn()

```
// to count the number of objects:
var enemyCount : int = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length;

if(enemyCount < maxEnemies){
Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
```

Comment: I need to set a limit. so in each difficulty level, enemies will spawn more.

Comment: You can change the value of maxEnemies to different values.  Are you trying to set successive waves of enemies?  In other words, should the enemies from one wave be completely destroyed before more enemies spawn?

Answer (score 1):

While using `CancelInvoke("spawn");` when you want to stop spawn enemies.

You should know about `CancelInvoke()` if you are playing with `invoke()` and `InvokeRepeating()`